# AWS elasticbeanstalk CLI Environment tier definition not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment * --application-name "rest-poc" --environment-name "rest-poc-env-v1" --version-label "1" --cname-prefix "rest12121-env-poc" --tags Key=owner,Value=dev --tier Type=Standard --solution-stack-name "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.4 running Docker 1.7.1" --option-settings file://~/options.json
```

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the CreateEnvironment operation: Environment tier definition not found

Can someone please tell me what is the correct syntax for specifying tier,since I want to try the worker tier of elasticbeanstalk

Comment: Probably too late at this point, but while I don't use this API, for awsebcli, the values are "server" and "worker" for Tier

Answer (score 0):

For standard environment we dont have to mention the tier option.
For worker we have to add --tier Type=worker